# How can I ask for user input from a thread in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, input, ipython

```
import time
import threading

def background_task():
    print('Doing something')
    time.sleep(10)
    input('Press enter to continue\n')
    print('Doing something else')
    time.sleep(10)
    print('Background task finished')


def start_background_task():
    t = threading.Thread(target=background_task)
    t.start()


def other_task():
    print('This is other task')
```

Hi everyone,

I would like to import this code into an iPython console, call `start_background_task()`, and while that is running call `other_task()`.

The problem here is that my code doesn't wait for me to press enter at `input('Press enter to continue\n')`.

I think I can see why inputs are ignored in threads, but then, what is the proper way to do this?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Would it work for you to start `other_task()` on a different thread at the beginning of or in the middle of `background_task()`, then call `background_task()` in the console?

Comment: That could be a good way to avoid the problems, but in my case, it's not possible. `background_task()` is a timer which I want to alert me at some moments and ask me to continue running. And `other_task()` could be any other thing I could be doing in between. Right now, I'm solving it with two consoles, but it would be great to have everything in the same one.